# Join 2 files by 2 columns, keeping all records using awk

Tags: unix, join, awk

I have 2 files I need to merge based on 2 columns. I have tried using awk as well as tried combining the 2 columns using _ and then using the join command. When using join, some records were not matched, even after sorting, and multiple records were created. Using awk `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($1,$2) in a{print $0, a[$1,$2]}' file 1 file 2`
 I can match the files correctly, but cannot get the output to print with zeroes when no match exists.

File 1:

```
chr   pos   SNP#
1     124   1
1     237   2
1     356   3  
2     107   4
2     224   5
```

File 2:

```
chr   pos   SNPHD
1     12    1
1     56    2
1     124   3
1     160   4
1     237   5
1     256   6  
1     354   7
2     107   8
2     185   9
2     224   10
```

Desired output:

```
chr   pos   SNP#   SNPHD
1     12    0      1
1     56    0      2
1     124   1      3
1     160   0      4
1     237   2      5
1     256   0      6
1     354   0      7
1     356   3      0
2     107   4      8
2     185   0      9
2     224   5      10
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated, I am new to large data files and unix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$3;next}
    {k=$1FS$2;print k,(a[k]?a[k]:a[k]*1),$3;delete a[k]}
     END{for(k in a)print k,a[k],"0"}' f1 f2
```

the result is not sorted:

```
chr pos SNP# SNPHD
1 12 0 1
1 56 0 2
1 124 1 3
1 160 0 4
1 237 2 5
1 256 0 6
1 354 0 7
2 107 4 8
2 185 0 9
2 224 5 10
1 356 3 0
```

for better format, you could pipe the result to `column -t`, also sort it if it is necessary

Comment: +1: Thanks Kent. I missed seeing the entry from first file. I deleted my answer as it would have turned out to be similar to yours, also thanks for looking out for me. Appreciate it! `:)`

Comment: Thank You! This is perfect, and yeah, just have to sort it and make it look pretty, but this is a huge help, and I would never have gotten that far on my own. I understand most of the code, but what is (a[k]?a[k]:a[k]*1) doing? I'd like to get better for the future as I'm handling files this size of bigger for the next couple years at least working on a PhD! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @slarmer1 this is just for handling the title line. if you can skip the header line, you can shorten that part into `(a[k]*1)` this convert empty (also the text like SNP#) value to `0`

Comment: I am trying to use this same code on a new set of files that I think are formatted the same way, however, when it finds a match, it is printing the matching SNP number on the next line > so it prints for example 1 12 1 (next line) 3

Comment: Any help with this would be greatly appreciated